# Java query with setString unable to insert bit type

Tags: java, mysql, bit, setstring

Here is the issue
I'm using Netbeans and MySQL latest version
I'm using the BIT(1) Field type in MySQL to manage the Boolean types in my app

When storing Data in the data base if I use this code everything works well

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `postetransfo`.`utilisateur`"
                + " (`dbLogin`, `dbMDP`, `dbNom`, `dbPrenom`, `dbAjPoste`, `dbModPoste`, `dbMajPoste`, `dbAjMesure`,"
                + " `dbModMesure`, `dbDroitAdmin`, `dbTracerAdmin`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,b'0',b'0',b'0',b'0',b'0',b'0',?)");

        st.setString(1, login);
        st.setString(2, "changemoi");
        st.setString(3, nom);
        st.setString(4, prenom);
        //st.setString(5, "b'0'");
        //st.setString(5, "b'0'");
       // st.setString(6, "b'0'");
       // st.setString(7, "b'0'");
       // st.setString(8, "b'0'");
       // st.setString(9, "b'0'");
        st.setString(5, "TEST");
```

But when I want to make all the query Dynamic I get the following exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'dbAjPoste' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4118)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
```

Comment: Seems like the data you're trying to put into the field `dbAjPoste` doesn't match the size of the actual data type in the schema.

Comment: you could try st.setBoolean() - but I'm not sure it'll work

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setBoolean` rather than `setString` for a BIT parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Data truncation: Data too long for column 'dbAjPoste' at row 1 means you want to store the more value than size present in DB.

**

- Example

**

1st coloum type Varchar2(5) but you want to insert string value like "abcdefghij".
The length of string is 10 but in DB it can take upto 5 only.

Hope it's useful for you..